# How to create a dataset in SSRS using Oracle stored procedure

Tags: oracle, reporting-services

I am trying to create a SSRS report using an Oracle stored procedure which has one input parameter and two output refcursors. The input parameter takes XML as its datatype.

How to run this stored procedure from SSRS?

This is the code which I am trying to use to create the dataset

```
PROCEDURE get_summary_rpt (
    p_xmlrequest            IN  CLOB,
    p_summary              OUT sys_refcursor,
    p_outputs               OUT sys_refcursor
);
```

Please advise

Answer (score 1):

SSRS will automagically map a single OUT REFCURSOR parameter and give you the results.  Two OUT REFCURSOR parameters probably won't work.

Answer (score 0):

SSRS is not set up to work with `OUTPUT` procedure parameters directly. Ideally, the procedure should have a `SELECT` statement in it that returns the results for your dataset. Then you would just tell it the procedure name, you don't have to write any SQL.

If you are unable to do that, you would need to write some PL/SQL to declare the variables, assign values to them using the procedure, and then use a `SELECT` statement to return them. If you write that all out and still have issues, post a specific question with the issue that you run into.